# Scroll Event Listener Not Triggering in Next.js Client-Side Component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, scroll

I'm developing a web application using Next.js 14.0.4 and React 18.2.0. My goal is to listen for scroll events on the entire page from a client-side component (specifically, a header component), but my scroll event listener does not seem to be triggered despite the component mounting successfully.

Here is the relevant code snippet from my header component:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const Header = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Header mounted'); // This logs correctly
    const handleScroll = () => {
      console.log('Current Scroll Position:', window.scrollY); // This never logs
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <header>
      {/* Header content */}
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

*Note that the issue also occur when I'm adding the EventListener to document instead of window*

Questions:

1. Is there a known issue with scroll event listeners in Next.js 14 or React 18 that could be causing this behavior?
2. Could Next.js's routing or page structure be interfering with the ability to detect scroll events at the window level?
3. Are there any best practices or alternative approaches recommended for attaching scroll listeners in a Next.js application?
4. Any insights or suggestions on how to debug this issue further would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve the problem by attaching the event listener to document.body instead of window

```js
const handleScroll = () => {
    console.log('scrolled!');
};

useEffect(() => {
    document.body.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => document.body.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely related to how Next.js handles its layout and the positioning of components.

Try the following and let me know if they work for you:

Check Component Positioning:
Ensure that your Header component is correctly positioned in the component hierarchy. If it's not at the top-level or not a direct child of the body element, it might not capture scroll events as expected. Make sure it's not within a container that has its own scrolling behavior.

Check CSS Styles:
Sometimes, CSS styles or layout configurations can affect the positioning and visibility of elements. Ensure there are no styles preventing the header from being at the top of the page.

Verify Page Structure:
Check if your application's page structure is affecting the scroll behavior. If you have multiple components handling different parts of the page, they might interfere with each other.

Answer (score 0):

To confirm the reason of the issue you are facing now, it needs to look over the whole component including JSX part.

But some cases I can advise you here are:

1. Check the height of scroll container element if it has been set with "%" and make sure it is set with 'px' or 'vh'
2. Check if it has been set as 'overflow: hidden'. If yes, reset it as 'auto'.
3. Since it is next app, if this is server-side component, window cannot be recognized.
   Add this:

   if (typeof window != "undefined") {
   window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll)
   }
4. Or try this out:

   window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll, true)